# setRemoteDescription on android fails on a SDP which does work between browsers. why?

Tags: android, webrtc, sdp

Debugging the android App I simply get:SessionDescription is NULL. 
On a line of code in my customsdpobserver.java file in the onSetFailure method.

My question is why? between chrome browsers I can set up a webrtc session without problem. But if I want to initiate a session from chrome to android, this error pops up.

I've seen people point to the msid values containing spaces, but in this case it doesnt. Even removing the streams doesnt seem to resolve the issue.

The SDP in question is this:

```
v=0
o=- 4372422506058837932 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114 115 116
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:Sv2H
a=ice-pwd:XXXSLr666XXXtHU6660PQXXX
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 64:55:C1:44:C6:03:21:4E:65:65:4F:35:45:D2:9B:A4:A2:31:B9:00:B3:73:D0:23:AB:FD:6B:AD:00:1E:F7:84
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:10 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:13 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd 1b2012c8-7179-4122-9a5b-c745382eba60
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 red/90000
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3124764907 4086243738
a=ssrc:3124764907 cname:BuikQrEhwdeJQ+dA
a=ssrc:3124764907 msid:ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd 1b2012c8-7179-4122-9a5b-c745382eba60
a=ssrc:3124764907 mslabel:ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd
a=ssrc:3124764907 label:1b2012c8-7179-4122-9a5b-c745382eba60
a=ssrc:4086243738 cname:BuikQrEhwdeJQ+dA
a=ssrc:4086243738 msid:ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd 1b2012c8-7179-4122-9a5b-c745382eba60
a=ssrc:4086243738 mslabel:ADairUjGkfAjrr5NRONe1a4bPXHH53n2SNxd
a=ssrc:4086243738 label:1b2012c8-7179-4122-9a5b-c745382eba60
```

I got this sdp from the data.sdp.toString(), done on the first line of the following code:

```
SessionDescription session = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, data.sdp.toString());
CustomSdpObserver observer = new CustomSdpObserver("localSetRemote");
localPeer.setRemoteDescription(observer, session);
```

On the last line the debugger breaks on onSetFailure. But SessionDescription is NULL. doesn't help me much, since it's definitely not NULL ;)

I expect android to just continue and NOT break on onSetFailure. It should create the answer next.

I will reward the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.. i got it working.. Just make sure not to pass in JSON with curly braces and stuff into the sessiondescription. Keep it plain text, just like your received it from your signaling server.

Anything that isn't SDP like it should be, gets rejected and you'll get this usefull SessionDescription is NULL. message.

But it's likely your own fault ;)

Comment: Are you... answering your own question like it's someone else's? I'm so confused.

Comment: I know it's been a long time but can you please explain what you mean about keeping it plain text? Are you saying that including `data.sdp.toString()` doesn't give you plain text? Or is that question above now edited to reflect your findings.

It would be good if you had answered your own question fully including the final code that actually works.

Comment: In my code I am taking the JSON that I receive and I parse it out as a JSONObject message using `JSONObject message = (JSONObject) arguments[1]` where arguments is `Object[]`. From that I then get my sdp like `String sdp = message.getString("sdp")` and it comes across as what can be seen [in the following GIST](https://gist.github.com/JohanJarvi/18c2b1f54a8b5c664b6f1ec057c0a02e). Does that look like the correct SDP or are you saying it needs to come through without the new line characters as well?